# iPhone C++/Objective-C exceptions

Tags: c++, objective-c, exception

does anyone know the consequences of enabling C++ exception handling in XCode for iPhone apps? It appears to be disabled by default.

Are C++ and Objective C exceptions the same or can C++ exceptions only be caught by C++ code and vise versa?

thanks

Comment: I thought I read something somewhere about LLDB's C++ support being limited (due to something about the 'unholy marriage'  of ObjC++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does anyone know the consequences of enabling C++ exception handling in XCode for iPhone apps?

It's the normal choice for C++ exception handling. If you are working with a C++ library, you will likely *need* this enabled.

You must not assume that exceptions will cleanly propagate across image boundaries. That is, you cannot assume that it is defined to throw *through* Foundation frames and catch on the other side. IOW, *throw MyLib->through Foundation->catch in MyApp* can result in undefined behavior. So, you must assume you need to catch these in MyLib.

Unlike OS X, the iPhone's C++ and ObjC exceptions are *not* implemented using 'Zero cost exceptions'. Zero cost exceptions, which favor execution speed over size, were not used because of the size of the unwind tables, and because of compiler support.

Enabling exceptions will require some speed and some size -- I expect that's less than 10% for most programs on iOS.

Ultimately, *need* should determine whether exceptions should be enabled or not, and they will introduce *some* execution and size overhead. Unless you are working with very specialized C++ libraries, you should assume that you need to enable them. However, the feature is supported.

> Are C++ and Objective C exceptions the same or can C++ exceptions only be caught by C++ code and vise versa?

In 64 bit OS X and iOS environments, C++ and ObjC exceptions can be caught using either handler. In 32 bit OS X, they use different exception models. Therefore, the 'catch all' expression (written in either lang) can catch *both* C++ and ObjC exceptions in iOS and 64 bit OS X, but not in 32 bit OS X.

Comment: Good answer. It'll be even better if you add appropriate links to the docs that spell these things out -- especially on the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: @Caleb some can be found in Apple's "Exceptions Programming Topics"